# Parse Returned Text into JSON Object in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, yql

**Solved:**

I was able to solve the problem in question with this:

```
if let returnedData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSString? {
                let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                let trimmedDataString = ((dataString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback", withString: "") as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(", withString: "") as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString: "")
                let dataFromDataString = trimmedDataString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                if let jsonObject: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataFromDataString, options: .allZeros, error: nil)  {
                    if let resultSet = jsonObject["ResultSet"] as! NSDictionary? {
                        println(resultSet)
                    }
                }

            }
```

**Original Question:**

I am currently using Yahoo! Finance's YQL to return data for stocks. I am able to query stocks and successfully return the wanted information, but only if I know the stock's symbol (AAPL, GOOG, FDX). However, I would like to be able to replicate the search functionality of iOS' Stocks application, which lets you perform a live search of stock symbols as you type a string.

When using [this](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2A%20from%20yahoo.finance.industry%20where%20id%20in%20(select%20industry.id%20from%20yahoo.finance.sectors)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys) URL to retrieve the information, I get a JSON response that is of no use to me:

```
{"query":{"count":0,"created":"2015-06-01T23:49:49Z","lang":"en-us","results":null}}
```

However, I have been able to find what I am looking for from [this](http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=k&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback) URL, but the data is not being returned in JSON format that I currently know how to handle:

```
YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback({"ResultSet":{"Query":"k","Result":[{"symbol":"K","name":"Kellogg Company","exch":"NYQ","type":"S","exchDisp":"NYSE","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"KNDI","name":"Kandi Technologies Group, Inc.","exch":"NMS","type":"S","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"KO","name":"The Coca-Cola Company","exch":"NYQ","type":"S","exchDisp":"NYSE","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"KMI","name":"Kinder Morgan, Inc.","exch":"NYQ","type":"S","exchDisp":"NYSE","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"KMB","name":"Kimberly-Clark Corporation","exch":"NYQ","type":"S","exchDisp":"NYSE","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"GMCR","name":"Keurig Green Mountain, Inc.","exch":"NMS","type":"S","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"KORS","name":"Michael Kors Holdings Limited","exch":"NYQ","type":"S","exchDisp":"NYSE","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"KLAC","name":"KLA-Tencor Corporation","exch":"NMS","type":"S","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"KRFT","name":"Kraft Foods Group, Inc.","exch":"NMS","type":"S","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"^KLSE","name":"FTSE Bursa Malaysia KLCI","exch":"KLS","type":"I","exchDisp":"Kuala Lumpur Stock Exchange ","typeDisp":"Index"}]}})
```

I have been searching all day for a way to convert this returned string into a JSON object for the use that I need in my application.

Since it is not coming back in a JSON format that I know how to parse with `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)`, I have been stuck in search for a way to create a JSON object from the string. Is there a direction that I can be pointed in that I'm just missing?

Comment: Try [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel). I've used it before to work with Youtube's API. Quite easy to implement.

Comment: Why do you think this is not a valid json?

Comment: @IcaroNZ I guess I didn't word my question correctly. I see that it is JSON, but I have not come across a JSON response that I have not been able to parse yet. When trying to parse the JSON, I get ```nil``` printed to the console.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't test the code below but if it does not work it should give you some ideas in how to solve it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let returnedData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSString? {
    let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    if let jsonObject: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataString, options: .allZeros, error: nil)  {
    if let resultSet = resultSet[yourDictionaryObject objectForKey:@"YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback"]
        //This should return a array of dictionary 
    }
}
```